# Как передать сообщение в функцию register_next_step_handler(call.message, func) при использовании Inline кнопок?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как я могу, с помощью inline кнопок, передать сообщение для следующей функции в
register_next_step_handler? С обычной клавиатурой всё понятно и всё работает))

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['exp'])
def exp(message):
    but_tcs = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='TCS', callback_data='exp_tcs')
    but_pcs = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='PCS', callback_data='exp_pcs')
    exp_menu = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    exp_menu.add(but_tcs, but_pcs)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выбери участок', reply_markup=exp_menu)

def exp_area(call, calldata, mess):
    if call.data == calldata:
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, mess)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(call.message, area)
```

При нажатии на кнопки ничего не происходит, он ждет сообщения от пользователя! Что нужно передать в функцию ниже?

```
def area(message):
    global plant_area
    plant_area = message.text
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введи название эксперимента')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, name_exp)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    if call.message:
        exp_area(call, 'exp_tcs', 'TCS')
        exp_area(call, 'exp_pcs', 'PCS')
```

С обычной клавиатурой и просто сообщениями пользователя всё работает, но хотелось бы сделать с inline кнопками))